# Description and Working of Multiple Processes in C

Tags: c, process

I am new to multiple processes in C.

Once a new child process is created in C, what all code is copied to that processes. 
I am confused as I am trying to create a child process but what would happen in its int main() function, since I am creating this child process from some other function.

I am working on Windows XP, VS2005.

I apologize for the confused question.

I would like to request for some documentation which would help me understand how to create and work with new processes in C

Comment: This depends on your platform. Pure C has no concept of multiple processes or forking. To get a useful answer, you'll need to provide more details about your specific environment.

Comment: I am working on Windows XP, VS2005. Please let me know, if any other details are required. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you should have a look at the winapi [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which creates a new process that runs the command you want, also check this example in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).